# jgFeed not parsing enclosure

Tags: jquery-plugins, rss

I'm parsing an RSS feed with [jgFeed](http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/jgfeed)

I get all the elements of the RSS (link,title,content..) except the enclosure value.

I have debugged with Firebug and it seems that jGFeed is not parsing the enclosure item

Here's the code that I have written.

```
$.jGFeed('rssurl',
  function(feeds){
    // Check for errors
    if(!feeds){
      // there was an error
      return false;
    }
    // do whatever you want with feeds here
    for(var i=0; i<3; i++){
      var entry = feeds.entries[i];
      // Entry title
                alert(entry.mediaGroups);
                /* alert (entry.link);
                 alert(entry.enclosure);
                 alert(entry.contentSnippet);
                 alert(entry.publishedDate);*/
    }
  }, 10);
```

How can I ensure that I parse the enclosure item?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ensure you run `console.log(feeds)` and breakdown the info you are getting from the rss feed that you are pulling data from.

[See this blog posting](http://jquery-howto.blogspot.com/2009/05/google-feeds-api-jquery-plugin.html).